# Acquiring 2nd Element of Uneven List

Tags: r, string, list, split

(question about lists in R)

I am working with a very large data set where I have a date column that takes one of two forms:

- date type 1: "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM"
- date type 2: "MM/DD/YYYYHH:MM:SS AM - MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM"

I need to split this column based on whether there is the dash in (type 2) and place them in two columns ("Date 1" and "Date 2"). If I encounter a row with a Type 1 date, then the date will simply occupy "Date 1" and the "Date 2" will simply be `NA`.

Here is what I am looking for—convert something that looks like this:

```
c(
    rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15),
    rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM - 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15)
  )
```

To this:

```
data.frame(
  Date1 = c(rep("8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15), rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15)),
  Date2 = c(rep(NA, 15), rep("8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15))
)

# output
# Date1                Date2
# 1  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   2  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   3  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   4  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   5  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   6  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   7  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   8  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   9  8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   10 8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   11 8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   12 8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   13 8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   14 8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   15 8/15/2018 9:18:45 AM                 <NA>
#   16 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 17 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 18 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 19 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 20 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 21 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 22 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 23 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 24 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 25 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 26 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 27 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 28 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 29 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
# 30 8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM
```

I want the first sub element of the list to occupy the `Date1` column and the second sub element (if it exists) to occupy the `Date2` column. If there is no second element, I want the `Date2` row to be `NA`.

My first try at this is to create a new list where I use a condition. If the length of the subelement is just one, I create the second sub element, and set it to `NA`.

```
dates = c(
  c(
    rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15),
    rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM - 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM", 15)
  )
)


# create the date split. Split the text based on the dash 
dates_split = strsplit(dates, " - ")
# note where the correct dates are. date_split[[15]] as one sub element and date_split[[16]] has two
dates_split[[15]];dates_split[[16]]

# so far so good






# create a conditional where if there is only one date (one sub element), set the second sub element to zero.
for(i in 1:length(dates_split)){
  if(length(dates_split[i]) == 1){
    dates_split[[i]][2] = NA
  } else {}
}

# the above loop does not behave as expected. The dates_split[[16]][2] is now gone (it turned to NA)






# create a vector for Date1 and Date2
Date1 = unlist(lapply(dates_split, "[[", 1))
Date2 = unlist(lapply(dates_split, "[[", 2))

# put each date type in their appropriate column
date_df = data.frame(
  Date1 = Date1,
  Date2 = Date2
)

# second column is all NA's. Where did the second sub elements go?
```

My previous script on a smaller data set did something like this to get around it:

```
dates = strsplit(dates, " - ")

# this takes forever to do. Is there a way to do this without using a loop??
for(i in 1:nrow(dates_split)){
  date_df$Date1 = dates[[i]][1]
  date_df$Date2 = dates[[i]][2]
}
```

The above is not very efficient. The real data set is over a million rows so it will take forever to load.

Is there any advice for how to modify this step so that I create the `NA` for the second sub element without inadvertently turn everything into an `NA`?

```
# create a conditional where if there is only one date (one sub element), set the second sub element to zero.
for(i in 1:length(dates_split)){
  if(length(dates_split[i]) == 1){
    dates_split[[i]][2] = NA
  } else {}
}

# the above loop does not behave as expected. The dates_split[[16]][2] is now gone (it turned to NA)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to answer the following

> Is there any advice for how to modify this step so that I create the
>   NA for the second sub element without inadvertently turn everything
>   into an NA?

just replace `[i]` with `[[i]]` in the second line of `for` loop.

Secondly, I made a few modifications to your code and tested for speed. It took about 15 seconds for 10 million data points.  So it is pretty fast.  I tried to replace the `for` loop with `lapply` but that did not result in any more speed.  Now you could speed it up (maybe significantly) using `data.table` package but there is some learning curve for that.  Here is the full code for testing to see if everything is working as your expectations.

```
# how many times to repeat dates (five million for testing)
rep.num = 5000000

# create dummy dates
dates = c(
    rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM", rep.num),
    rep("8/20/2018 9:18:45 AM - 8/12/2018 9:18:45 AM", rep.num)
)

# create the date split. Split the text based on the dash 
# using fixed = T here results in significant speed increase
dates_split <- strsplit(dates, " - ", fixed = T)

# note where the correct dates are. date_split[[rep.num]] as one sub element and date_split[[rep.num + 1]] has two
dates_split[[rep.num]]
dates_split[[rep.num + 1]]
dates_split[[rep.num + 1]][1]
dates_split[[rep.num + 1]][2]

# create a conditional where if there is only one date (one sub element), set the second sub element to zero.
for(i in 1:length(dates_split)){
  if(length(dates_split[[i]]) == 1){
    dates_split[[i]][2] = NA
  }
}

# put each date type in their appropriate column
date_df = data.frame(
  Date1 = sapply(dates_split, "[[", 1),
  Date2 = sapply(dates_split, "[[", 2)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. Looks like in my original code I did not construct my if-then statement correctly. I accidentally wrote `if(length(dates[[i]] == 1)){...}`. Thus, it treated each instance as `T` and set everything to `NA`'s. But I did learn to use the `sapply()` instead of unlisting the `lapply()`. Thanks!